AWS Runtime.ImportModuleError
I've been attempting to build & deploy a MicroService via SAM.
All I updated were credentials in the samconfig.toml and env.json files. The only other thing I changed was in tsconfig - "importsNotUsedAsValues" was deprecated so I removed it.
After running sam build & sam deploy --config-env prod --guided, now the MicroService appears to be broken.
I made sure packages were installed before as well, and also ran tsc before deploying.
How to resolve?
AWS Live Tail Logs:
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 168.17 ms Phase: init Status: error Error Type: Runtime.ExitError

INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:16.v33 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2::runtime:0163909785ec2e11db2b64bb2636ada67bb348dd5764aa83e7eb011bc0f365d8 ```

